Can't run project due to: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'prototype')
When I try to run my react application, I'm running into the following error:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'prototype') at ./node_modules/probe-image-size/lib/common.js (common.js:13:1)

From what I can find, this is a dependency for plotly.js. I've tried using newer versions of plotly, as well as downgrading react and what node verson is used, though the latter caused far more issues. I've also tried only having probe-image-size as a dependency, as well as installing the latest version through npm.
This occurs after I run npm start, and let the project load. I'd expect to at least make it to the login page.
For what I'm using:

React version 18.3.1
Node version 18.12.1
Webpack version 5.94.0
React-script version 5.0.1
plotly.js version 2.27.1

While not code I've written, the code from the node_modules file that has the issue is as follows
'use strict';
 
 
var Transform    = require('stream').Transform;
var streamParser = require('stream-parser');
 
 
function ParserStream() {
  Transform.call(this, { readableObjectMode: true });
}
 
// Inherit from Transform
ParserStream.prototype = Object.create(Transform.prototype);
ParserStream.prototype.constructor = ParserStream;
 
streamParser(ParserStream.prototype);
 
 
exports.ParserStream = ParserStream;
 
 
exports.sliceEq = function (src, start, dest) {
  for (var i = start, j = 0; j < dest.length;) {
    if (src[i++] !== dest[j++]) return false;
  }
  return true;
};
 
exports.str2arr = function (str, format) {
  var arr = [], i = 0;
 
  if (format && format === 'hex') {
    while (i < str.length) {
      arr.push(parseInt(str.slice(i, i + 2), 16));
      i += 2;
    }
  } else {
    for (; i < str.length; i++) {
      /* eslint-disable no-bitwise */
      arr.push(str.charCodeAt(i) & 0xFF);
    }
  }
 
  return arr;
};
 
exports.readUInt16LE = function (data, offset) {
  return data[offset] | (data[offset + 1] << 8);
};
 
exports.readUInt16BE = function (data, offset) {
  return data[offset + 1] | (data[offset] << 8);
};
 
exports.readUInt32LE = function (data, offset) {
  return data[offset] |
    (data[offset + 1] << 8) |
    (data[offset + 2] << 16) |
    (data[offset + 3] * 0x1000000);
};
 
exports.readUInt32BE = function (data, offset) {
  return data[offset + 3] |
    (data[offset + 2] << 8) |
    (data[offset + 1] << 16) |
    (data[offset] * 0x1000000);
};
 
 
function ProbeError(message, code, statusCode) {
  Error.call(this);
 
  // Include stack trace in error object
  if (Error.captureStackTrace) {
    // Chrome and NodeJS
    Error.captureStackTrace(this, this.constructor);
  } else {
    // FF, IE 10+ and Safari 6+. Fallback for others
    this.stack = (new Error()).stack || '';
  }
 
  this.name = this.constructor.name;
 
  this.message = message;
  if (code) this.code = code;
  if (statusCode) this.statusCode = statusCode;
}
 
// Inherit from Error
ProbeError.prototype = Object.create(Error.prototype);
ProbeError.prototype.constructor = ProbeError;
 
 
exports.ProbeError = ProbeError;

